# How would you open a Dialog when an edit box is selected? MFC 2005

Tags: mfc, dialog, keyboard, editbox

I would like to be able to create an onscreen keyboard to popup whenever an edit field is selected. I am using MFC Visual studio 2005 (C++ based).

Below is my code so far:

```
void CTestHarnessDlg::OnEnChangeEdit3()
{
    CKeyboard Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();
}
```

When I run the Dialog box and click on the selected field, it does not open an onscreen keyboard until I press a key on the keyboard. Is there a way to open the keyboard without putting anything into the text field?

I've been looking at ON_EN_SETFOCUS, but I'm very new to MFC. I'm not sure how to even use the CEDIT command classes within the code... Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: with "DLL" did you mean Dialog box?

Comment: Yes, Dialog box. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to add commands using Visual Studio Class Wizard

in Visual Studio, open your project, then in the upper menu go to:

- Project>Class Wizard
- select your project and your class name(in your case
  `CTestHarnessDlg`)
- on the `Commands` tab in the search field type your Edit ID
- Select it and the ListBox called `Messages` will be filled with all the messages from that control
- Select `EN_SETFOCUS` and press `Add Handler` and type a name that you want or leave the default one
- then press OK or `Edit Code` and you should be right there on the method implementation
- everything should be set and created automatically by the class wizard: Method declaration, Method Implementation, Message Map

## How to add commands manually

- Go to your class declaration(usually in the .h file) and add the method declaration, you will have to know the type of the function you need to add

  `afx_msg void OnSetfocusEdit();`
- go to the message map (usually in the cpp file) and add the mapping, you will have to know the macro that you have to use, in this case ON_EN_SETFOCUS

  `ON_EN_SETFOCUS(IDC_YOUR_EDIT_ID, &CTestHarnessDlg::OnSetfocusEdit)`
- go to your cpp (usually in the cpp file) and add the method implementation

```cpp
void CTestHarnessDlg::OnSetfocusEdit()
{
    TCHAR sysDir[MAX_PATH];
    if( !GetSystemDirectory( sysDir,  MAX_PATH) )
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return;
    }
    ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"osk.exe", _T("") , sysDir, SW_SHOW);
}
```

## using osk.exe

the command `ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"osk.exe", _T("") , sysDir, SW_SHOW);` will open window's on screen virtual keyboard, you don't ahve to create your own keyboard dialog there is already one by default on windows

## not using osk.exe

you will have to create your own dialog (CKeyboard) but IMO you shouldn't use [CDialog::DoModal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/619z63f5.aspx) method, you should make the dialog modeless using [CDialog::Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/yhth57kd.aspx) then use [CWnd::ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/72szh9c7.aspx) and then use [CWnd::SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx) to move your dialog where you want.

Comment: awesome, this sounds promising! I'll implement this.